How to configure a global logger outside the main package in Golang
I'm new to Golang, coming from nodejs.
At the moment I'm just playing around and trying to figure out how to port some logic from some old project into the new language.
I'm usually very concerned about the structure of projects and the separation of duties, to try to keep everything tidy.
For example, one thing I often do is write a library dedicated to the global logger, make it exportable and then call it wherever I need it.
Now in Golang I find myself a bit confused with this concept, or rather I have not yet found examples or an exhaustive guide that implements this pattern.
I've noticed that creating a global variable for the logger is often discouraged.
I don't like placing my global logger configuration in main.go because I'd like to keep everything separate, so I ended up implementing something like this:
// pkg/logger/logger.go

package logger

import (
"log/slog"
"os"
)

func init() {
   
    var loggingLevel = new(slog.LevelVar)

    logger := slog.New(slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stderr)

    // Other configurtions stuff ...

    slog.SetDefault(logger)
}

And in the main.go:
//cmd/main.go

package main

import (
    _ "pkg/logger"
    logger "log/slog"
    ...
)

func main(){

    logger.Info("log from logger")

    ...
}

Now I'm able to call the logger wherever I need it, simply by importing the standard lib slog.
Everything works fine, but at this point I ask myself, is my implementation considered a good practice?
Or is this a clear antipattern?
Are there better and more consolidated solutions?
Are there any drawnbacks by creating a separate library this way and then just calling the init function from main?
I know that I will probably receive many opinionated answers but I am very interested to understand how to best structure everything right from the beginning of my golang jurney and then not think about it anymore and always reuse the patterns that I have consolidated.

slog.Default() is one approach (use slog.SetDefault() to store your logger then Default() whenever you need it). Take a look in the slog source to see how this is implemented. "many opinionated answers" - probably more likely the question will be closed - you may find this of interest.

@Brits Thank you for your feedback, very appreciated. Anyway I', actually using the slog.Default() approach. My question was more related to the pattern that I'm using. is It a good practice to separate the logger logic in a dedicated package and leverage the init func by importing it in the main? Furthermore I wondering if possible to change some logger attribute runtime other than the log level..(ex. allow the source if the log level is changing to debug)

Personally I suspect you are over thinking this (logging does not need to be complex). I generally create the logger in main and then pass an slog.Handler around, that way you can add context (also see this).

I knew about the Context and I find it a useful and interesting concept. Anyway maybe you're right when you say 'over thinking' but when I came with a medium size project with a microservice architecture I need some abstractions and capabilities like for example 'switch off' the logger, change level or enrich the output at runtime. I'm trying some solutions but I try to avoid to reinvent the wheel when possible. It seems it's no easy to find a lot of tutorial around that go in 'depth'..Maybe It's a positive aspect because it makes you want to rewrite everything by yourself.

I suspect "the context" you mention is not what I was referring to. I meant logger.With (so, for example, when processing data for a user you pass a logger that includes the users ID). context.Context (what I suspect you were referring to) is something different; but it's also possible to store the logger in a ctx (as it's common for most functions to accept a context). The issue with tutorials is that they are opinions (and the proposed method may not be right for you); there is not really one "correct" approach here.
